# In Visual Studio 2015, is it possible to run Package Manager Console commands via a MSBuild task?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, ef-code-first

I have been searching the web for this and must be missing something.  Seems like it would be a trivial thing to do.

If you know how to run a PMC command via MSBuild task, and can provide an example XML/code snippet (from MSBuild), it would be appreciated.

Comment: maybe merge this with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38548811/in-visual-studio-is-it-possible-to-run-an-ef-add-migration-initialcreate-co into one question?

Comment: @stijn--Thanks for looking, but I felt that these were two distinct questions that could both benefit the community if answered.  Thanks again.